# Does DataContext.Connection share settings accross different Datacontexts

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, database-connection, datacontext

When using linq2sql to access a database, I create a new DataContext. As far as I understand, the underlying DBConnection is pooled, and may be reused.

```
using (var dc = new DB_DataContext())
{ 
    //dc.Connection may be persistent across multiple DataContexts
}
```

Now, I have found in various blogs and here on stackoverflow, that one can change certain properties of the connection, without the overhead of a transaction:

```
// the following query should preferably be terminated, 
// in case of a deadlock with a more important query
dc.ExecuteCommand("SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY LOW");

// the following query should be aborted, if it takes too long to acquire the locks
dc.ExecuteCommand("SET LOCK_TIMEOUT 50");

// the following query can handly dirty reads and should not acquire read locks
dc.ExecuteCommand("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED");
```

But this seems quite dangerous to me.

Is it actually safe to execute those commands on the current DataContext, or does this "poison" the connection pool with non-standard connections?
Is it possible that these settings persist accross different DataContexts?

If so, is there a safe way to e.g. change the deadlock priority for a linq2sql query, without forcing a new transaction, or is this generally ill-advised?

Comment: I can't answer definitively, but I would guess the connection pool doesn't contain any 'state' information, but just means the overhead of a connection is removed, therefore you aren't poisoning the pool, just your usage of the connection until it has been released back to the pool.

Comment: My uncertainty is this: If it is all the same connection, how can the SQL server know that it should no longer apply the previous `SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY` settings when a new DataContext reuses the connection? It is possible that linq2sql takes care of all this somehow, but I do not see how.

Comment: Opening a connection is an expensive operation.  Resetting a load of values to their default is cheap.  It is possible that when the application 'closes' a connection ,it sends a command down the wire to the server to say 'reset everything, and pretend this connection is brand new'.